# How can request.param be annotated in indirect parametrization?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, type-hinting

In the [Indirect parametrization example](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization) I want to type hint `request.param` indicating a specific type, a `str` for example.

The problem is since the argument to `fixt` must be the [`request`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#request) fixture there seems to be no way to indicate what type the parameters passed through the *"optional `param` attribute"* should be (quoting the documentation).

What are the alternatives? Perhaps documenting the type hint in the `fixt` docstring, or in the `test_indirect` docstring?

```py
@pytest.fixture
def fixt(request):
    return request.param * 3

@pytest.mark.parametrize("fixt", ["a", "b"], indirect=True)
def test_indirect(fixt):
    assert len(fixt) == 3
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of now (version 6.2), `pytest` doesn't provide any type hint for the `param` attribute. If you need to just type `param` regardless of the rest of `FixtureRequest` fields and methods, you can inline your own impl stub:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    class FixtureRequest:
        param: str
else:
    from typing import Any
    FixtureRequest = Any


@pytest.fixture
def fixt(request: FixtureRequest) -> str:
    return request.param * 3
```

If you want to extend existing typing of `FixtureRequest`, the stubbing gets somewhat more complex:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from pytest import FixtureRequest as __FixtureRequest
    class FixtureRequest(__FixtureRequest):
        param: str
else:
    from pytest import FixtureRequest


@pytest.fixture
def fixt(request: FixtureRequest) -> str:
    return request.param * 3
```

Ideally, `pytest` would allow generic `param` types in `FixtureRequest`, e.g.

```
P = TypeVar("P")  # generic param type

class FixtureRequest(Generic[P]):
    def __init__(self, param: P, ...):
        ...
```

You would then just do

```
from pytest import FixtureRequest

@pytest.fixture
def fixt(request: FixtureRequest[str]) -> str:
    return request.param * 3
```

Not sure, however, whether this typing is agreeable with the current `pytest`'s codebase - I guess it was omitted for a reason...

Comment: The last solution would be ideal, it would make lots of sense. (Perhaps someone reading this will post a feature request on GitHub.) Excellent answer!

Answer (score 5):

Following up on hoefling's answer regarding generics, you can wrangle the generic into the TYPE_CHECKING code:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Generic, TypeVar

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from pytest import FixtureRequest as _FixtureRequest
    T = TypeVar("T")
    class FixtureRequest(_FixtureRequest, Generic[T]):
        param: T
else:
    from pytest import FixtureRequest
```

Then code like this will work, though you may need to quote the type hint since pytest's FixtureRequest is not generic at runtime:

```
@pytest.fixture
def fixt(request: "FixtureRequest[str]") -> str:
    return request.param * 3
```