# How to specify mypy type pytest_configure fixtures?

Tags: python, pytest, mypy

I am trying to specify mypy type hints for the pytest native fixtures I am using in my test project e.g.:

```
import pytest

def pytest_configure(config):
    # Do something useful here
```

The `config` fixture returns a `_pytest.config.Config` object. If I try to model this naively:

```
import pytest

def pytest_configure(config: Config) -> None:
    # Do something useful here
```

I receive a mypy error:
`conftest.py:3: error: Name 'Config' is not defined  [name-defined]`

I could do `from _pytest.config import Config`, but this doesn't seem to be a good way, because _pytest is private.
Another option would be to ignore the type with `# type: ignore`. If this is the recommended way I would of course do this, but I wonder if there is a better option.

I have the same issues in with any kind of pytest native fixtures I use, e.g. `request` which is used for parameterized fixtures. This would be a `_pytest.fixtures.FixtureRequest`.

Comment: `from _pytest.config import Config` is the way to go since `Config` is not exported by `pytest` ATM for some reasons. Feel free to [open a new issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/new?template=2_feature_request.md), though. For `request` typing, check out [my other recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65342113/2650249) and the related [issue #8073](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/8073).

Comment: Thanks, if you put that as answer, I will accept it.
Opened https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/8202

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Importing `from _pytest.config`

Since `pytest` doesn't currently export `Config` (as of 6.2), the only way for typing is to use `from _pytest.config import Config`. This is how I also type `config`, as can be seen e.g. in [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61213745/2650249):

```
from _pytest.config import Config

def pytest_configure(config: Config) -> None:
    ...
```

You can track the typing progress in this `pytest` issue: [#7469](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/7469).

#### Custom type stubs

You can also introduce a small custom type stub that hides the reexport. It's questionable whether it will be useful here, only worth to mention for an alternative solution. If you create a file `_typeshed/pytest.pyi` with the following contents:

```
from typing import Any
from _pytest.config import Config as Config

def __getattr__(name: str) -> Any: ...  # incomplete
```

and make it accessible to `mypy` in `mypy.ini`:

```
[mypy]
mypy_path = _typeshed
```

Now you can import `from pytest import Config` at least in type checking mode - the runtime import will still fail. So the imports would look like

```
from typing import Any, TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from pytest import Config
else:
    Config = Any


def pytest_configure(config: Config) -> None:
    pass
```

The only benefit of that solution is that the private import is now hidden; I'd still go with the private import though.